# How to Specify Transport When Calling wp_remote_post()

Tags: wordpress

I have a plugin that calls wp_remote_post. I want to have an option to specify the transport, because for some users, curl is throwing an error in specific circumstances.

What's the best way to do this?

I tried using the requests-requests.before_request action, but I don't know how to get the options to be passed by reference. Wordpress states in the documentation for do_action_ref_array that the parameters will not be passed by reference.

I had this code:

Before calling wp_remote_post:

```
        add_action( 'requests-requests.before_request', array( __CLASS__, 'before_request' ), 10, 5 );
```

Then the function:

```
public static function before_request( $url, $headers, $data, $type, &$options ) {
    $options['transport'] = 'Requests_Transport_fsockopen';
}
```

No success, though.